# Why my client does not receive data from server that is sent from interrupt function?

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I have to send data to the client in the interrupt function. But apparently, the client cannot receive the data. The server did get the data sent from the client but the client cannot reply back.

When I try the communication in void loop it is a success. But once I put it in the interrupt, I cannot get the data back. The data that the server has to send is simply a number which will then trigger the led at the client side. It is really helpful if someone can help me figure it out.

This is part of the server code.

```
void ICACHE_FLASH_ATTR detectsMovement() {
 LightValue = LightSensor.GetLightIntensity();  
 Serial.print("Light: ");
 Serial.println(LightValue);
 if (LightValue < threshold )
 {
    Serial.println("MOTION DETECTED!!!");
    analogWrite(led, 1023);
    startTimer = true;
    lastTrigger = millis(); 
    WiFiClient client = server.available();
    if (client) {
      if (client.connected()) 
      {
         digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  // to show the communication only 
         (inverted logic)
         Serial.println("");
         String request = client.readStringUntil('\r');    // receives the 
          message from the client
         Serial.print("From client: "); Serial.println(request);
         client.flush();
         client.println("1\r");      // sends the answer to the client
         digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      }
    client.stop();                // terminates the connection with the client
   }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);                   // only for debug
  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);       // forces to use the fix IP
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);                 // connects to the WiFi router
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }

   pinMode(motionSensor, INPUT_PULLUP);
   // Set motionSensor pin as interrupt, assign interrupt function and set RISING mode
   attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(motionSensor), detectsMovement, RISING);

   server.begin();        // starts the server

   pinMode(light, INPUT);
   LightSensor.begin();  
   Serial.println("Running...");

   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}
```

And the client code

```
   void loop () {
  client.connect(server, 80);   // Connection to the server
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);    // to show the communication only (inverted logic)
  Serial.println(".");
  client.println("Hello server! Are you sleeping?\r");  // sends the message to the server
  String answer = client.readStringUntil('\r');   // receives the answer from the server
  Serial.println("from server: " + answer);
  if (answer  == "1")
  {
    Serial.println("Success!");
    analogWrite(D0, 512);
  }
  client.flush();4
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(2000);                  // client will trigger the communication after two seconds
}
```

The client supposed to get the value '1'. I don't know what to do.

Comment: don't do the communication in interrupt. set a flag variable with interrupt and handle things in loop()

Comment: 'Cause serial communications use often (quite always) ISR (interrupt sub-routine) it's not a good idea to manage serial communications in an other ISR. Often (quite always) the ISR starts with a CLI (CLear Interrupt) that inhibit the CPU to call other ISR till the previous ISR ends (or STI SeTInterrupt instruction is issued). (Not in all CPUs the instructions CLI and STI have this name, some CPUs may manage automatically and/or programmatically this two instruciont).

Comment: Doesn't look like C to me.

Comment: If I remember right, the Arduino is programmed in (some kind of) C++. So, none of your tags [tag:c] or [tag:c#] apply. [tag:c++] seems to me more appropriate. (Sorry, tag spamming is considered as rude.)